# Product collection sorting broken in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, sorting, bug

I am trying to sort by price on a product collection query, however, it seems sorting by price is reducing the result set to 0...

Here is a working query which returns expected number of products (865)

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('my_product_type', ['eq' => 383]);
die(var_dump($productCollection->count()));
```

By merely adding sorting, the result set is reduced to 0...

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('my_product_type', ['eq' => 383])
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
die(var_dump($productCollection->count()));
```

Reindexing does not solve the problem. It looks like some JOINs introduced by the `setOrder` clause are responsible for reducing the result set to 0 items.

I found [this bug report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18264), with [this patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/14ab8ace12f0e95a476675548d0712d5ecaf9a26#diff-5a30a751305f50e9d7bbd8a2576a2b46), which I've verified is on my 
system.

I have also tried using `addAttributeToSort` instead of `setOrder`; the result is the same.

It seems tied to filtering the product set by my custom attribute, for when I try this

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
```

It works as expected.

Is it something I'm doing wrong, or a bug, or perhaps something is off with my product data?

**EDIT**
I've added the SQL from the 3 queries above. It looks like the JOIN on `catalog_product_entity_int` + `catalog_product_index_price` is what may be breaking things?

```
First Call: 
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_my_product_type.value_id > 0, at_my_product_type.value, at_my_product_type_default.value) AS `my_product_type` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_my_product_type_default` ON (`at_my_product_type_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_my_product_type_default`.`attribute_id` = '593') AND `at_my_product_type_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_my_product_type` ON (`at_my_product_type`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_my_product_type`.`attribute_id` = '593') AND (`at_my_product_type`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE ((IF(at_my_product_type.value_id > 0, at_my_product_type.value, at_my_product_type_default.value) = '383')) AND (e.created_in <= '1547298780') AND (e.updated_in > '1547298780')

Second Call: 
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_my_product_type.value_id > 0, at_my_product_type.value, at_my_product_type_default.value) AS `my_product_type`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_my_product_type_default` ON (`at_my_product_type_default`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_my_product_type_default`.`attribute_id` = '593') AND `at_my_product_type_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_my_product_type` ON (`at_my_product_type`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_my_product_type`.`attribute_id` = '593') AND (`at_my_product_type`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE ((IF(at_my_product_type.value_id > 0, at_my_product_type.value, at_my_product_type_default.value) = '383')) AND (e.created_in <= '1547298780') AND (e.updated_in > '1547298780') ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` ASC

Third Call: 
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (e.created_in <= '1547298780') AND (e.updated_in > '1547298780') ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` DESC
```

Comment: you have tried this  `$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC');` instead of `->setOrder('price', 'ASC');`

Comment: Yes, the result is the same.

Comment: I would suggest to dump the SQL for your 3 variants and look at what the difference is - it seems strange, indeed, since the join of the price index table and the join of an custom attribute shouldn't interfere

Comment: I've added the SQL for each query in my original question.

Comment: @HelgeB This is the clause that hoses the result set `INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`  ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id `. That means there are no prices indexed for the products in my `my_product_type` set?

Comment: Looks like there are no index records for the products I'm interested in. By taking an `entity_id` from the first query, then looking directly in `catalog_product_index_price` I find there are 0 records: `select count(*) from catalog_product_index_price where entity_id = 70178; ` (0 results) Is it a bug with the indexer?

Comment: The SQL statements are OK in my opinion. So, yes, it looks like all the products with   `my_product_type` set don't have an entry in the price index table. There is something going wrong with your price indexing if you already have tried to reindex

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the products were not *enabled*, and moreover the indexer only considers products which are enabled.

After crafting a query to bulk enable the products and rerunning the indexer, the queries work as expected.